# App crashes when only one line in textview for spannable string

Tags: android

I am using spannable string to show read more for long paragraphs in `textview`. However it might happen that there is only one line or two three words in the textview for which read more is not needed. But the app crashes with out of bound error.

Below is the code:

```
public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;

  public void setDescription(String description) {
        TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);    
        addReadMore(description,post_desc);
  }



private void addReadMore(final String text, final TextView textView) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 320) + "...\nread more");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    addReadLess(text, textView);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple, getTheme()));
    } else {
    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
    }
    }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length() , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    private void addReadLess(final String text, final TextView textView) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text + "\nread less");
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    addReadMore(text, textView);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    super.updateDrawState(ds);
    ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    ds.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple, getTheme()));
    } else {
    ds.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
    }
    }
    };
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length() , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(ss);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }

    }
```

> Error message:
>       `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; regionStart=0; regionLength=270`

Comment: could you please format your codes? just insert space X4 for each indention.

Comment: I am using stackoverflow of so its kind of difficult to format the code. Please bare with me  @hjchin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that you must use instead of:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 320) + "...\nread more");
```

is:

```
if (text.length() > 320) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text.substring(0, 320) + "...\nread more");
} else {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text);
}
```

also every time you use:

```
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, ss.length() - 10, ss.length() , Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

are you sure that `ss.length() - 10` and `ss.length()` are valid start and end portions of `ss`?

Comment: I got this code from a tutorial. Not sure about the `ss.length-10` thing.